# A bipartite graph question

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is there a bipartite graph with degrees $3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6$?

I've been stuck attempting to draw this graph but keep getting lost. I think it is no, but I am not concrete about it. Is it no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re right: there is no such graph. Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are the two parts. The sum of the degrees is $44$, so there are $22$ edges, each with one vertex in $V$ and one in $W$. Thus,

$$\sum_{v\in V}\deg(v)=\sum_{v\in W}\deg(v)=22\;.$$

Let $v$ be the vertex of degree $5$, and without loss of generality assume that $v\in V$. Then every vertex in $W$ has degree a multiple of $3$, so $3\mid\sum_{w\in W}\deg(w)=22$, which is absurd.